# Get logged-in user inside Azure API Management Developer portal's custom page

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

**Question 1**

I have created a custom page inside Azure API Management Developer Portal. Inside that custom page I have to get logged in user's ID or Email. I have to pass this value to my REST API to do some operations. I searched many places I did not find any way, how to fetch logged in user's ID or Email inside Azure API Management Developer portal?.

**Question 2**

Can we display this custom page only for admins or can we restrict a page based on logged in users role inside Azure API Management Developer Portal?

Please help me to find out solution for this.